# How to not real time filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building on my practice web app and I'm tried to filter the data from fetched data but it filter real time. My question is how to make it not real time, like when searchbar is empty it will fetch all data but when type a text in searchbar it will fetch data from input text.

Here is my code

```
  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(BASE_URL)
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
  const [inp, setInp] = useState("")

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
  }

  if (loading) return <h1> LOADING...</h1>

  if (error) console.log(error)

  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <div className="Container">
        <label className='header'>Topic</label>
        <div className="Container-searchBar">
          <input type="Text" value={search} placeholder="Search . . ." onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
        {data.filter((val) => {
          if (search === "") {
            return val
          }
          else if (val.tags.includes(search)) {
            return val
          }
        }).map((post) => {
          return 
.
My return
.

        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

I'm new to React and JS so sorry for some bad question.

Comment: just save all the data in a state and display normally, when the user enters text listen for onChange event and filter the data and use that data to display using conditional statement. That's all

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to save all the data in a state , can you give me an example? Thank you.

Comment: You fetch the data via a api call after the data is fetched its saved to a useState hook and then you display it. then do the above and filter the fetched data simply. If too much filtering then you can debounce it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get what you mean by not real-time filtering.
Your approach is okay, if you would like not to apply to filter immediately, you can apply timeout.

```
const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(BASE_URL);
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
const [filteredStates, setFilteredStates] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setFilteredStates(data);
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    const filter = data.filter((state) => {
      return state.tags.includes(search);
    });

    setFilteredStates(filter.length ? filter : data);
  }, 300);
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [search, data]);

const handleChange = (e) => {
  setSearch(e.target.value);
};

if (loading) return <h1> LOADING...</h1>;

if (error) console.log(error);

return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="Container">
      <label className="header">Topic</label>
      <div className="Container-searchBar">
        <input
          type="Text"
          value={search}
          placeholder="Search . . ."
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      {filteredStates.map((post) => {
        return;
        <></>;
      })}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: like not render fetched data with every input character but rendering only the words that really want to.

Comment: I have added the complete code above, hope it will work for you as expected.

Comment: It's work really well, thank you so much. But the next problem is it not fetch all the data when input is empty can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: It not render anything when I reload the page but it render when I typing something and delete it, like when I typing "D" it not render anything but when I delete "D" the fetched data comes up.

Comment: Yeah, need to consider data loading, I have added loading as dependency check again.

Comment: now the data comes up and disappear immediately lol

Comment: what about now )

Comment: still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not the complete answer you are looking for, but usually you would have to apply conditional trigger for your filter, such as

```
const onSearchPress = () => {somehowQueryYourData ...... setSearchState(true)}
```

However, the problem with the info I gave you so far has an issue which I am currenlty facing :
the setSearchState(true) does not get turned off once you trigger the onSearchPress, which in turn creates a real time filter in the end. Hope you can build-on something from this.